# MIB3 Agent K time travels..to when?

Tags: men-in-black

In MIB3, Agent K uses this special gun to time travel from his apt. When and where does he go? We never see the older Agent K in the most of the movie till the very end when Agent J comes back. So where did Agent K go and what did he do? Or is that for MIB4?

Answer (score 10):

I think you've misunderstood what happens at that part of the film.  K doesn't time travel, he is erased from time since he was killed in the past.

The gun is just a 'normal' gun.  With Boris having escaped earlier K assumes that he might come after him again, not knowing that Boris plans to time travel.